# Grab certain text with sed and sort+input back into file

Tags: bash, sed, formatting

I would like to request some help.

I am currently creating a script that would have a set file full of formatted text as a base, and then input and delete from that text file in accordance to user input. I would be putting this into the bash script.

I have figured out how to grab the text I need out of the file using this:

```
sed -n '/5.1.1"/,/|}/p' textfile.txt
```

The 5.1.1 is the rack location of my server, and I'm grabbing the text of the file until it finds |}.

This outputs something along the lines of:

```
|+  description = "5.1.1";
|-
|1: ~servername~ [4U];
|-
|5: servername [2U];
|-
|7: servername [2U];
|-
|9: servername [2U];
|-
|11: servername [2U];
|-
|15: servername [2U];
|-
|17: servername [2U];
|-
|19: servername [2U];
|-
|21: ~servername~ [2U];
|-
|23: servername [2U];
|-
|25: servername [2U];
|-
|29: servername [2U];
|-
|31: servername [2U];
|-
|33: servername [2U];
|-
|35: ~servername~ [2U];
|-
|37: ~servername";
|-
|39: servername;
|-
|41: switch;
|}
```

And so on and so forth going up to 5.1.15.

The sed just picks the text I need to change out.

My way of thinking how to do this would be to take the text I grab with sed, insert the line I need, and then sort it based on the number in the second column and reinsert the altered text back into the file in the same location, however I do not know how to implement this.

The line I would be inputting would be in the same format as the other lines and then I would out a |- below it.

Thank you very much

Edit 1:

A desired output would be thus:

I have the line 16: servername; that I would like to input into this file in the rack 5.1.1.

The end result from taking the base from above would be:

```
|+  description = "5.1.1";
|-
|1: ~servername~ [4U];
|-
|5: servername [2U];
|-
|7: servername [2U];
|-
|9: servername [2U];
|-
|11: servername [2U];
|-
|15: servername [2U];
|-
|16: servername;
|-
|17: servername [2U];
|-
|19: servername [2U];
|-
|21: ~servername~ [2U];
|-
|23: servername [2U];
|-
|25: servername [2U];
|-
|29: servername [2U];
|-
|31: servername [2U];
|-
|33: servername [2U];
|-
|35: ~servername~ [2U];
|-
|37: ~servername";
|-
|39: servername;
|-
|41: switch;
|}
```

Edit 2:

I figured I should include the script I wrote to do the formatting. It's incomplete and pretty janky but it does the trick besides the if for the $location variable. I need to rework the regex for that.

```
#! /bin/bash


function serverread {

#Enter the location
function locationread { 
echo 'Enter the location of the server in the data center in format (x.x.x) ex. 5.1.15'
read location

if [[ "$location" =~ [0-9]{1,2}.[0-9]{1,2}.[0-9]{1,2} ]]
then
          echo "Success"
  else
            echo "You have entered an incorrect format for the rack, please try again."
            locationread
            exit
fi
}
locationread

echo Please enter the rack space at which the server was placed
read rp

if (( $rp < 1 || $rp > 42));
then
        echo You have entered an incorrect size for the server. Please enter a number between 1 and 42.
        read rp
else
{
        echo You entered: $rp as the server placement in the rack.
}
fi
#Enter the server name
echo Now please enter the server name "(Use ~ around the name if it is disconnected/unplugged)":
read name

if [[ $name == ~* ]] && [[ $name == *~ ]];
then
        echo "You entered: $name as the server name and it is currently disconnected in some way."
else
        echo "You entered: $name as the server name."
fi

#Enter the physical height of the server
echo Now please enter the size in height of the server:

function readsize {
read size
if [ $size -eq $size 2>/dev/null ]
then
        if (( $size < 1 || $size > 42));
        then
                echo You have entered an incorrect size for the server. Please enter a number between 1 and 42.
                readsize
        else
                echo "You entered: $size as the physical height of the server"
        fi
fi
}
readsize

#if (( $size == 1))
#
#  else
#                echo "$size is not an integer"
#        fi
#       
#if (( $size < 1 || $size > 42));
#then
#        echo You have entered an incorrect size for the server. Please enter a number between 1 and 42.
#        read size
#else
#        echo "You entered: $size as the physical height of the server"
#fi

if (( $size == 1));
then
        echo Currently this is the line that will be entered: $rp": "$name";"
else
        echo Currently this is the line that will be entered: $rp": "$name" ["$size"U];"
fi
echo Is this correct? '[yes/no]'
read matrix
echo Would you like to add another server? '[yes/no]'
read matrix2

if (( $matrix == "yes" ));
then
        if (( $matrix2 == "yes" ));
                then
                        serverread
        else
                        echo This is complete
                exit
        fi
else
        echo Please run this command again
        exit
fi
}
serverread
```

Edit 3:

This is what I changed the last function to to fit it into the script:

```
set finale="($rp": "$name" ["$size"U];""
echo Is this correct? '[yes/no]'
read matrix
echo Would you like to add another server? '[yes/no]'
read matrix2

if (( $matrix == "yes" ));
then
        {
        # all text before 5.1.1
        sed -n '/'"$location"'"/q;p;' racktext.txt;
        # parse text in this section
        sed -n '/'"$location"'"/,/|}/p' racktext.txt | input.sh
        # all text below this section
        sed -n '/'"$location"'"/{ :a; /|}/{ n; :b; p; n; bb; }; n; ba; };' racktext.txt
        # use sponge to overwrite the file in a pipeline
        } | sponge racktext.txt
        if (( $matrix2 == "yes" ));
                then
                        serverread
        else
                        echo This is complete
                exit
        fi
else
        echo Please run this command again
        exit
fi
}
serverread
```

And this is how I was going to do the script that you showed me in a separate file:

```
#! /bin/bash

export $(cat rackformat | grep -v ^# | xargs)
echo $finale

while IFS= read -r l; do 
        if [[ "$l" =~ description ]]; then            
                msg="$l"$'\n';                 
        elif [[ "$l" =~ "}" ]]; then                    
                { 
                        echo -n "$msg" | grep -v '|-'; 
                        echo "\|$finale"; 
                } | sed 's/^|//' | sort -n | sed 's/^/|/' | while IFS= read -r l; do 
                echo "$l"; 
                echo '|-'; 
        done | head -n-1; 
        echo '|}'; 
else 
        msg+="$l"$'\n'; 
fi; 
done
```

Edit 4:

I didn't include the above portion because I didn't think it was going to be relevant however I probably should have included it and that's my bad. this is the text file before the input:

```
{| class="wikitable"
|
{| class="wikitable"
|+  description = "5.1.1";
|-
|1: ~servername~ [4U];
|-
|5: servername [2U];
|-
|7: servername [2U];
|-
|9: servername [2U];
|-
|11: servername [2U];
|-
|15: servername [2U];
|-
|17: servername [2U];
|-
|19: servername [2U];
|-
|21: ~servername~ [2U];
|-
|23: servername [2U];
|-
|25: servername [2U];
|-
|29: servername [2U];
|-
|31: servername [2U];
|-
|33: servername [2U];
|-
|35: ~servername~ [2U];
|-
|37: ~servername~;
|-
|39: servername;
|-
|41: servername;
|}
|
{| class="wikitable"
```

And this is the output of the current script:

```
{| class="wikitable"
|
{| class="wikitable"
|\|2.: test [2U];
|-
|+  description = "5.1.1";
|-
|1: ~servername~ [4U];
|-
|5: servername [2U];
|-
|7: servername [2U];
|-
|9: servername [2U];
|-
|11: servername [2U];
|-
|15: servername [2U];
|-
|17: servername [2U];
|-
|19: servername [2U];
|-
|21: ~servername~ [2U];
|-
|23: servername [2U];
|-
|25: servername [2U];
|-
|29: servername [2U];
|-
|31: servername [2U];
|-
|33: servername [2U];
|-
|35: ~servername~ [2U];
|-
|37: ~servername~;
|-
|39: servername;
|-
|41: servername;
|}
|
{| class="wikitable"
```

And here is the entirety of the current script:

```
#! /bin/bash


function serverread {

#Enter the location
function locationread {
echo 'Enter the location of the server in the data center in format (x.x.x) ex. 5.1.15'
read location

if [[ "$location" =~ [0-9]{1,2}.[0-9]{1,2}.[0-9]{1,2} ]]
then
          echo "Success"
  else
            echo "You have entered an incorrect format for the rack, please try again."
            locationread
            exit
fi
}
locationread

function parser {
while IFS= read -r l; do 
        if [[ "$l" =~ description ]]; then            
                msg="$l"$'\n';                 
        elif [[ "$l" =~ "}" ]]; then                    
                { 
                        echo -n "$msg" | grep -v '|-'; 
                        echo "\|$finale"; 
                } | sed 's/^|//' | sort -n | sed 's/^/|/' | while IFS= read -r l; do 
                echo "$l"; 
                echo '|-'; 
        done | head -n-1; 
        echo '|}'; 
else 
        msg+="$l"$'\n'; 
fi; 
done
}

echo Please enter the rack space at which the server was placed
read rp

if (( $rp < 1 || $rp > 42));
then
        echo You have entered an incorrect size for the server. Please enter a number between 1 and 42.
        read rp
else
{
        echo You entered: $rp as the server placement in the rack.
}
fi
#Enter the server name
echo Now please enter the server name "(Use ~ around the name if it is disconnected/unplugged)":
read name

if [[ $name == ~* ]] && [[ $name == *~ ]];
then
        echo "You entered: $name as the server name and it is currently disconnected in some way."
else
        echo "You entered: $name as the server name."
fi

#Enter the physical height of the server
echo Now please enter the size in height of the server:

function readsize {
read size
if [ $size -eq $size 2>/dev/null ]
then
        if (( $size < 1 || $size > 42));
        then
                echo You have entered an incorrect size for the server. Please enter a number between 1 and 42.
                readsize
        else
                echo "You entered: $size as the physical height of the server"
        fi
fi
}
readsize

#if (( $size == 1))
#
#  else
#                echo "$size is not an integer"
#        fi
#       
#if (( $size < 1 || $size > 42));
#then
#        echo You have entered an incorrect size for the server. Please enter a number between 1 and 42.
#        read size
#else
#        echo "You entered: $size as the physical height of the server"
#fi

if (( $size == 1));
then
        echo Currently this is the line that will be entered: $rp": "$name";"
else
        echo Currently this is the line that will be entered: $rp": "$name" ["$size"U];"
fi

echo Is this correct? '[yes/no]'
read matrix
echo Would you like to add another server? '[yes/no]'
read matrix2

finale=$rp": "$name" ["$size"U];"
echo $finale

if (( $matrix == "yes" ));
then
        function b {
        # all text before 5.1.1
        sed -n '/'"$location"'"/q;p;' racktext.txt;
        # parse text in this section
        sed -n '/'"$location"'"/,/|}/p' racktext.txt | parser
        # all text below this section
        sed -n '/'"$location"'"/{ :a; /|}/{ n; :b; p; n; bb; }; n; ba; };' racktext.txt
        # use sponge to overwrite the file in a pipeline
        }
        b | sponge racktext.txt
        echo $
        if (( $matrix2 == "yes" ));
                then
                        serverread
        else
                        echo This is complete
        fi
else
        echo Please run this command again
        exit
fi
}
serverread
```

Comment: please add an example of desired output to your question

Comment: There will be text above and below these as well, like if I'm inputting into rack 5.1.5 then there will be a similar set of text for 5.1.4 above and 5.1.6 below

Comment: This looks like you should write your own (big) bash parser for this. To insert smth back to the file, you need to extract all text before the token, all text after the token, and then write just new file with substituted text in the middle.

Comment: Mmm I could look into that, the problem is this is something I'm looking to implement as part of a script that woudl take variables and format them into the |16: servername; line and then grab the file and just kinda slam it in there. would a bash parser even work for something like that if I need to run it multiple times in one go?

Comment: Cool, you can use `readarray` to read lines to array variable, then you can simply index it, that is a cool idea. You can run multiple times, but one at a time (or in different environment) ; ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following `script.sh` works for the example passed on stdin as you provided:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r l; do 
    if [[ "$l" =~ description ]]; then 
       msg="$l"$'\n'; 
    elif [[ "$l" =~ "}" ]]; then 
         { 
           echo -n "$msg" | grep -v '|-'; 
           echo '|16: servername;'; 
         } | sed 's/^|//' | sort -n | sed 's/^/|/' | while IFS= read -r l; do 
           echo "$l"; 
           echo '|-'; 
         done | head -n-1; 
         echo '|}'; 
     else 
         msg+="$l"$'\n'; 
     fi; 
done
```

For the following input:

```
|+  description = "5.1.1";
|-
|1: ~servername~ [4U];
|-
|5: servername [2U];
|-
|7: servername [2U];
|-
|9: servername [2U];
|-
|11: servername [2U];
|-
|15: servername [2U];
|-
|17: servername [2U];
|-
|19: servername [2U];
|-
|21: ~servername~ [2U];
|-
|23: servername [2U];
|-
|25: servername [2U];
|-
|29: servername [2U];
|-
|31: servername [2U];
|-
|33: servername [2U];
|-
|35: ~servername~ [2U];
|-
|37: ~servername";
|-
|39: servername;
|-
|41: switch;
|}
```

it outputs the following:

```
|+  description = "5.1.1";
|-
|1: ~servername~ [4U];
|-
|5: servername [2U];
|-
|7: servername [2U];
|-
|9: servername [2U];
|-
|11: servername [2U];
|-
|15: servername [2U];
|-
|16: servername;
|-
|17: servername [2U];
|-
|19: servername [2U];
|-
|21: ~servername~ [2U];
|-
|23: servername [2U];
|-
|25: servername [2U];
|-
|29: servername [2U];
|-
|31: servername [2U];
|-
|33: servername [2U];
|-
|35: ~servername~ [2U];
|-
|37: ~servername";
|-
|39: servername;
|-
|41: switch;
|}
```

As you didn't provide any description of the format of this file nor other examples, I assumed:

- the lines `|-` can be ignored and stripped away and will never change (at first I thought those are empty rags, but then they are between 15 and 16 and 17, so not)
- the sections start with description and end with `|}`

To insert this back to the script you can:

```
{ 
     # all text before 5.1.1
     sed -n '/5.1.1"/q;p;' textfile.txt;
     # parse text in this section
     sed -n '/5.1.1"/,/|}/p' textfile.txt | script.sh
     # all text below this section
     sed -n '/5.1.1"/{ :a; /|}/{ n; :b; p; n; bb; }; n; ba; };' textfile.txt
 # use sponge to overwrite the file in a pipeline
 } | sponge textfile.txt
```

Comment: The lines are actually there in the finished thing. The |- inbetween them signifies a new line in a table and the | on the line itself implies an entry into the table. The |} signifies the end of the table and the |+ is the title of it. There is one line above it but since all I would be changing is the entries in the table it didn't matter too much.

Comment: I'll give what you did a shot! I'll let you know how it goes! Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. So I tried to reformat the code that you sent to use the variables that would be read in for the description section (5.1.1 etc.) and I don't think it's working properly. When I try to run the script, I'm getting command not found "script_from_this_post_above.sh" and command not found "sponge" (I did rename the .sh to the script name that I created). I'll post what I changed it to in an edit.

Comment: Och, sorry, I meant the `script_from_this_post_above.sh` to be the while read loop code snipped with shebang above I posted above, didn't make that clear. The [sponge](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sponge) is an utility from moreutils, if you don't have it, you can `var=$( command ); printf "%s" "$var" > textfile.txt`, however be aware that command substitution will remove trailing empty newlines. Or you can `tmp=$(mktemp); { commands } > $tmp; mv $tmp textfile.txt` alternatively using temp file.

Comment: You are awesome! I'll give this a shot. :)

Comment: By the way, did I do the alterations to the sed commands correctly to account for the variable $location? Also am I able to put the script.sh into a function and pass the second sed command to that function?